# Boolean indexing in pandas dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

I'm trying to apply boolean indexing to a pandas DataFrame.

**nm** - stores the names of players

**ag**- stores the player ages

**sc** - stores the scores

**capt** - stores boolean index values

```
import pandas as pd 
nm=pd.Series(['p1','p2', 'p3', 'p4'])
ag=pd.Series([12,17,14, 19])
sc=pd.Series([120, 130, 150, 100])
capt=[True, False, True, True]
Cricket=pd.DataFrame({"Name":nm,"Age":ag ,"Score":sc}, index=capt)
print(Cricket)
```

Output:

```
       Name  Age  Score
True   NaN  NaN    NaN
False  NaN  NaN    NaN
True   NaN  NaN    NaN
True   NaN  NaN    NaN
```

Whenever I run the code above, I get a DataFrame filled with NaN values. The only case in which this seems to work is when capt doesn't have repeating elements.

i.e When `capt=[False, True]` (and reasonable values are given for nm, ag and sc) this code works as expected.

I'm running **python 3.8.5, pandas 1.1.1** Is this a deprecated functionality?

Desired output:

```
        Name  Age  Score
True    p1   12    120
False   p2   17    130
True    p3   14    150
True    p4   19    100
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael I've included teh desired output in my question now. And you also got it in your answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set index values for each Series for avoid mismatch between default RangeIndex of each Series and new index values from `capt`:

```
capt=[True, False, True, True]
nm=pd.Series(['p1','p2', 'p3', 'p4'], index=capt)
ag=pd.Series([12,17,14, 19], index=capt)
sc=pd.Series([120, 130, 150, 100], index=capt)

Cricket=pd.DataFrame({"Name":nm,"Age":ag ,"Score":sc})
print(Cricket) 
      Name  Age  Score
True    p1   12    120
False   p2   17    130
True    p3   14    150
True    p4   19    100
```

**Detail**:

```
print(pd.Series(['p1','p2', 'p3', 'p4'])) 
0    p1
1    p2
2    p3
3    p4
dtype: object

print(pd.Series(['p1','p2', 'p3', 'p4'], index=capt)) 
True     p1
False    p2
True     p3
True     p4
dtype: object
```

---

[`Boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) is filtration:

```
capt=[True, False, True, True]
nm=pd.Series(['p1','p2', 'p3', 'p4'])
ag=pd.Series([12,17,14, 19])
sc=pd.Series([120, 130, 150, 100])

Cricket=pd.DataFrame({"Name":nm,"Age":ag ,"Score":sc})
print(Cricket) 
  Name  Age  Score
0   p1   12    120
1   p2   17    130
2   p3   14    150
3   p4   19    100

print (Cricket[capt])
  Name  Age  Score
0   p1   12    120
2   p3   14    150
3   p4   19    100
```

Comment: @perpetuallyperplexed - Because index values of Dataframe are inherited from `Series.index`, if different, get mismach and misisng values, similar like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193488/create-python-pandas-series-from-dict-problem-to-assign-index?noredirect=1&lq=1)